# Datepicker set by day of year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

This is a followup to a previous question about Datepicker. Trying to show only every third day on the calendar. figured out how to get DOY as integer and use in calendar, however it fails every March - also not able to span two years?

On a second part, if I need to disable a certain day of the week, how do I combine that with current 3rd day feature.

here is [JSFiddle DatePicker](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/nbL98a2r/7/)

```
function noWeekEnds(date) {
  var dow = date.getDay();
  if(dow>5 || dow<1) return [false,''];
  return [true,''];  
}

function unavailable(date) {

  var now = date;
  var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  var diff = now - start;
  var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
  var shift = (day%3===0);

    return [shift, "red2", "available"];
    return noWeekEnds(date);

/*
need this to span across 2 years i.e.: Jan 8 2015 thru Jan 12/2016

also it fails the 3rd week of every March ???
*/
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
  });

$('#datepicker').attr('readonly',true);
});
```

Comment: `return noWeekEnds(date);` will never work as this function ends on first return.

Comment: example of how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed unavailable function:

http://jsfiddle.net/nbL98a2r/13/

```
function unavailable(date) {
    var start = new Date(2015,0,8);
    var end = new Date(2016,0,12);
    var now = date;
    if(now < start || now > end) return [false, "red2", "available"]
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(now.getTime() - start.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    var nwe = noWeekEnds(date);
    var shift = (diffDays%3===0) && nwe[0];

    return [shift, "red2", "available"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why March shifts in the 3rd week but not any other months?

Comment: still trying to figure this one out. It seems that your function is sometimes "reseting" itself.

Comment: new version in answer. now you have correct times every third day from to date without weekends :) if you want to enable days "outside" range just change `false` in `if` to `true`. Also you might consider using `minDate`, `maxDate` params of jQuery datepicker.

Comment: Thanks looks great!!! - Still has shift in the month of March - don't know why? Also dates shift between Dec and Jan due to the new year and DOY resets to 1 from 365.

Comment: To be honest I don't see any shift in there. can you explain a bit more what do you mean by that?

Comment: In your Fiddle look at March, it shifts on March 6 to March 10 when it should be March 9 (every 3rd day)

Comment: look at your on March 31 - it should be March 30

Comment: This was due to daylight savings :) new version in answer, should be perfect now :)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much !!! I would have never figured that out. - my only thing left id the same shift between years... the Jan 2016 skips a day...

Comment: Which day exactly? I have: 31 Dec 2015 True, 6 Jan 2016, 12 Jan 2016. Which is ok because 3rd and 9th of January 2016 are weekends.

Comment: Actually I think your last fix might have resolved it... I was think that the DOY when it reached 365 and started over at 1 was shifting - I'm not fully clear on the calculations to derive the day of year, but it seems ok now - thanks so much for your time!!!